# SQL (mysql) query improvement

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

First of all, let me explain my data structure.

I have a model called profile, witch is a profile for a service provider. The service provider may choose from two diferent types of "travels" (both and none of them also). The first travel mode is "I can go to the client". For that, the service provider needs to input all cities he can travel for (many-to-many). The second "travel" mode is "My client can come to me". Those, he chooses the city he is placed from a list (one-to-many).

For the "I can go to the client" travel mode, I have a locals_profile table with a profile_id and a local_id and a locals table with the city name.

For the "My client can come to me", I have a locations table with profile_id and city_id and a cities table with the name of the city.

Before you ask, because of other things in the project modeling, I couldn't use the same table for the city name in both cases (if I could, the performance would be increased?).

Also, the profile belongs to many sub_categories, witch bring us another table called profiles_sub_categories with sub_category_id and profile_id field.

What I want is, given a sub_category, show how many items I have in each city. Eg:

- For the "designers" sub category:

  - New york (100)
  - San Fracisco (50)
  - Miami (10)
  - ... (max 10 cities)

I've acomplished what I wanted with the following query:

```
select q1.city_name, if(q1.city_count is null, 0, q1.city_count) + if(q2.city_count is null, 0, q2.city_count) city_count
from
  (select l.name as city_name, count(*) as city_count from locals_profiles lp
  inner join locals l on l.id = lp.local_id
  inner join profiles p on p.id = lp.profile_id
  inner join profiles_sub_categories ps on ps.profile_id = p.id
  where ps.sub_category_id = 97 and l.level = 2
  group by 1) q1
left join
  (select c.name as city_name, count(*) as city_count from cities c
  inner join locations lo on lo.city_id = c.id
  inner join profiles p on lo.profile_id = p.id
  inner join profiles_sub_categories ps on ps.profile_id = p.id
  where ps.sub_category_id = 97
  group by 1) q2
on q1.city_name = q2.city_name
order by 2 DESC
limit 10;
```

But the query is taking too long to be executed. Since it's a web application, I need it to be almost instantly. Does anyone knows a better way to do what I'm trying?

Comment: You certainly should be able to use the same table for the city, assuming you have foreign keys you can reference - although this won't necessarily help performance.  Which brings me to my bad news - city names are **not** unique.  You should be able to otherwise pull the shared tables from the subqueries out, `q1.city_count` will never be null, and you should be using the standard `COALESCE()` instead of that `if` construct.  My design senses are telling me there's something slightly off about this, if you have two 'city' tables...

Comment: You are probably right about my design, but I can't afford the effort of merging the tables by now. Since it is not the main reason of the poor performance I rather solve it later, witch bring us back to the main question of this thread, on how to improve this query.

Comment: Do the ids for the city rows match, in `locals` and `cities`?  Otherwise, this isn't going to work (city names are non-unique).  Also, I've generally seen table names as _singular_.  Also, don't order by column number - things could get weird if you change what column is where (especially in mySQL, with things like `GROUP BY`...).

Comment: Your query is summarizing a lot of information, presuming most or all of those tables have a significant number of rows in them.  The top-ten pattern you're using `ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 10` means that the query has to look at everything. Have you used `EXPLAIN` with the query? Have you checked that you have the correct indexes on your tables to let the MySQL server optimize it?  Sometimes it's necessary to create a new table holding this kind of data, then use a MySQL event to repopulate it once an hour. That works well for bragging-rights data like what you're generating here.

Answer (score 0):

I've found mysql doesn't do a great job of optimizing queries. The easy solution is writing two queries and merging them in the application layer. Suprisingly, it will probably be faster...

Alternatively, you could try eliminating the views (q1,q2) and aliasing the same tables multiple times instead. Might  be tough to get right....